# How do i change a property in state whose name is the value of a variable?

Tags: reactjs

I have a quick question about reactjs that hopefully someone can answer. Lets keep it short and sweet.

I have a property in state:

```
    this.state = {
        property: []
    }
```

This property is an array. I would like to change one of the properties inside of the array:

```
    this.setState({
        property:{
            index: value,
        }
    });
```

I have 'index' passed as a variable into my state changing function. Index is a number. The value of the index will be something such as '0', '1', '2'... etc. 
Doing what I did above will set the value of the property 'index' which is not what I want. How would I instead change the value of the property that has the name stored in the variable 'index'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
const index = 'dummy'
const value = 69
this.setState({
    property:{
        [index]: value,
    }
});

// after the state updated 
console.log(this.state.property.dummy); // 66
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he/she is looking for. It's a array, not an object.

Comment: The property in state is an array, but it is an array of objects, so this in fact does work.

Comment: @FlamePrinz Oh, my mistake then

Answer (score 2):

You create a copy, assuming index being the position where you want the change to happen and value being the new value you can use this

```
this.setState({
        property: this.state.property.map((anItem, i) => (i === index) ? value : anItem) 
    });
```

If your real state happens to have more properties you'll need to use this

```
this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        property: this.state.property.map((anItem, i) => (i === index) ? value : anItem) 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not directly mutate anything in `this.state`. You are supposed to let React handle that, so make a shallow copy of it and manipulate that.

```
const newProperty = [...this.state.property];
newProperty[index] = value;
this.setState({property: newProperty});
```

If you want to use ES5 to make the copy, do this instead:

```
const newProperty = this.state.property.slice();
```